How to install geopandas on termux
i cant seem to understand what am i doing wrong on termux
i tried everything
i ran
pip install geopandas

it doesent seem to work
to install 'geopandas' on termux
it always gets stuck i dont know why
the error:
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from geopandas) (1.26.4)
Collecting pyogrio>=0.7.2 (from geopandas)
  Using cached pyogrio-0.9.0.tar.gz (352 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from geopandas) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.4.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from geopandas) (2.2.2)
Collecting pyproj>=3.3.0 (from geopandas)
  Using cached pyproj-3.6.1.tar.gz (225 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting shapely>=2.0.0 (from geopandas)
  Using cached shapely-2.0.5.tar.gz (282 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      Compiling shapely/_geometry_helpers.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling shapely/_geos.pyx because it changed.
      [1/2] Cythonizing shapely/_geometry_helpers.pyx
      [2/2] Cythonizing shapely/_geos.pyx
      running egg_info
      writing shapely.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to shapely.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to shapely.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to shapely.egg-info/top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
          from . import multiarray
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
          from . import overrides
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
          from numpy._core._multiarray_umath import (
      ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_ValueError" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311.so"...

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
          from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
          from numpy._core._multiarray_umath import (
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
          raise ImportError(msg)
      ImportError:

      IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

      Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
      many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
      installed.

      We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

          https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

      Please note and check the following:

        * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3.11"
        * The NumPy version is: "2.0.0"

      and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
      Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

      Original error was: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_ValueError" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/_core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311.so"...


      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 210, in <module>
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 108, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 970, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 956, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 310, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-qphif5z_/shapely_2576136fc96a4c58ab3c4866b6781b20/versioneer.py", line 1995, in find_sources
          super().find_sources()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 318, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 539, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 577, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 102, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 250, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 334, in _add_defaults_ext
          build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 303, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 111, in ensure_finalized
          self.finalize_options()
        File "<string>", line 132, in finalize_options
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-lhg5tp1n/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
          raise ImportError(msg) from e
      ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
              its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
              your python interpreter from there.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I am just frustrated i want to run a script i cant
Can anyone help i will appreciate it
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Please post your complete error message

Did you read this: ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.

It is recommended that you use conda to install geopandas. The advantage of using the conda package manager is that it provides pre-built binaries for all the required and optional dependencies of GeoPandas for all platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux).
If using pip to install GeoPandas, you need to make sure that all dependencies are installed correctly. The main dependencies (shapely, pyproj, pyogrio) provide binary wheels with dependencies included for Mac, Linux, and Windows.
However, depending on your platform or Python version, there might be no pre-compiled wheels available, and then you need to compile and install their C dependencies manually. See https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html

how to install conda

Conda can be obtained by installing the Anaconda Distribution (a free Python distribution for data science), or through miniconda (minimal distribution only containing Python and the conda package manager). See also the Conda installation docs for more information on how to install Anaconda or miniconda locally.

Mind that using the conda "defaults" channel is not always free: anaconda licensing. For most organisations with > 200 people, it is easier/safer to install miniforge, which is ~miniconda but with only conda-forge as standard configured channel.

Miniforge3 will now be installed into this location:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/miniforge3

Press ENTER to confirm the location
Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
Or specify a different location below

[/data/data/com.termux/files/home/miniforge3] >>>
PREFIX=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/miniforge3
Unpacking payload ...
Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 328: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/miniforge3/_conda: cannot execute: required file not found    it shows this error
